# calling Javascript setInterval function without delay argument

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I want to know what is the default delay of setInterval function ie. the delay when we do not pass the delay value upon calling the function. I searched for it but did not find it.

Comment: 4ms is the minimum. At least for browsers. Where do you want to use it?

Comment: I am making an analog clock mini-project

Comment: In the browser?

Comment: I am writing the code on codePen

Comment: ...therefore it runs in the browser.

Comment: Just know setTimeout/Interval are not accurate

Comment: @VLAZ 4ms is the minimum when there are nested setIntervals. See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval#Delay_restrictions) and [Reasons for delays longer than specified](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified)

Comment: @VLAZ is 4ms defined somewhere - I have used down to 1 (most browsers) and many will accept 0 (not had success with FF on that though).

Comment: @AHaworth See the links in my last comment. You can enter whatever value you want, but the browser may throttle the actual value used.

Comment: @HereticMonkey thanks, I seem to have forgotten that detail. I was searching for an SO answer for that but I can't seem to find one.

Comment: @AHaworth [Here is the standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/timers-and-user-prompts.html#dom-setinterval). The minimum is zero, the nesting level can set it to `4`. Check step 10 and onwards. You can always set a *lower* value, but it's not going to be used.

Comment: Guys what I want to be sure of is that if I don't pass the delay argument the delay will be 4ms?

Comment: @VLAZ thanks, yes true for nested calls, I was thinking of one-off which of course isn't too useful when you are creating a timepiece or similar.

Comment: The delay will be 0. Which means "at the next turn of the JavaScript event loop". We can't give you an exact amount of time because it depends on when the `setTimeout` method is called and when the event loop ends, and is browser-dependent anyway.

Comment: I'm curious to know which documentation pages you found that were unsatisfactory. 
If I search for "setInterval" I get [w3schools.com's documentation of setInterval](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) which states: _milliseconds Required. The intervals (in milliseconds) on how often to execute the code. If the value is less than 10, the value 10 is used._ Which isn't entirely accurate, and certainly doesn't tell the whole story, but it also doesn't fall in the category of "I searched for it but did not find it." You should say what you found in your question.